# How can I get Google to not index archive pages in Blogger?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, blogger

I'm using Blogger with a custom domain. When I use the Google search `site:example.com`, the top results are in the form `Example: 2010-01-10`. These are archive pages that Blogger generates. My relevant content pages only show up after all of these, on page 2 or 3. Ideally I don't even want these pages to appear in Google results.

I believe that the reason they are indexed is because I have the "Blog Archive" panel enabled. Which I enabled so that there are links to all the content pages in my site. Some of my pages are only linked to through this Blog Archive panel, so they wouldn't be indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is to add this inside the `<head>` tags in your site's template - this should be a conditional piece of code that adds a `noindex` meta tag to ONLY your archive pages:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "archive"'>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
</b:if>
```

See [more on blogger template variables](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=10274&answer=47270).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to put a `rel=nofollow` in your anchor tag.  I am not sure if you have access to do that.  Otherwise if you are looking for a change through Blogger then this question is best suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions.